# What does this mean and How do i fix it?

Tags: java, histogram

```
if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
        catOne++;
        System.out.println("");
```

//variable catOne might not be initialized

Comment: If it's a local variable, it means you have to assign a value to it (like `0`) before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

It means, you have to initialize catOne, e.g. with `catOne = 0;` before reading it (witch of course the `++` operator does).